# Heroku PHP development - Best practice to deal with production config file

Tags: php, heroku

In my own cms system, I have a config file that is not registered in git (i.e. it is listed in .gitignore), but I will need to have that config file available on server.

What is the best practice to do this on Heroku environment?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options that immediately come to mind; presented here in order of preference from strongest to lowest:

1. Use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). They will be available in `$_ENV` or via `getenv()`, and that's the most portable approach. If you add any add-on on Heroku, the corresponding information will be set as config vars so you can read from the environment at runtime. For instance, when you `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql`, there will be a `DATABASE_URL` config var that looks roughly like this:

   ```
   $ heroku config | grep DATABASE_URL
   DATABASE_URL: postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398
   ```

   You can then read this info from the environment and parse it as a URL to determine all the connection details:

   ```
   $dbinfo = parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
   ```

   The same applies to any add-on. If you add a RedisToGo add-on from the add-ons store, you'll have a `REDISTOGO_URL` env var with the connection info. If you add a Mandrill add-on, you'll have a `MANDRILL_APIKEY` that you can use to interact with the API.

   This is the recommended [Twelve-Factor practice](http://12factor.net/config) and has three very clear advantages:

   1. if you want/need to change a config setting, you don't have to re-reploy your app
   2. you can deploy the same code without changes to e.g. a production and a staging app (also see the `heroku fork` feature), not to mention local dev environments, as these only differ in their config vars
   3. on occasion, **the values of config vars may change**. For instance, [the Heroku Postgres HA feature may cause the value of `DATABASE_URL` to change](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-ha). If you hard-code the value into your app, it'll go down when this happens and you have to re-deploy. If you dynamically at runtime read from `getenv("DATABASE_URL")`, you'll be safe.

   Remember that you can set any config var yourself, e.g. `heroku config:set FOO=bar` and then `$foo = getenv("FOO")` or `$foo = $_ENV["FOO"]` (the former has the advantage of not throwing a notice if the variable/key doesn't exist, so you can do `$foo = getenv("FOO")?:"default value"`).
2. Use something like [IncenteevParameterHandler](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler)
3. Use the [`composer compile` step](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#custom-compile-step) to copy/move a `config.php-dist` to `config.php` (or similar) during `git push heroku master`
4. Do the same as above but using a Composer `post-install-cmd`; however, that will run every time someone does `composer install`, so it's probably not what you want.
5. Remove the config from `.gitignore` :)

P.S. Only option #1 reads config vars at runtime so you're automatically safe in the event the value of a config var changes.

Comment: Thank you especially for the reference to mandrill as that is what we are going to use in this project too.